# How can I add a tab control to a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, tabs

Project description:

Hi, on my project I have 64 client´s they communicate with my main station on a one wire `asynchronous` bus, now I want to monitor the communication between them. For that I have a `RichTextBox` , In that box I see the whole data traffic. Now I want to implement the possibility that when I select a client for example nr. 4 that opens a new `RichTextBox` on a tab control of my main `RichTextBox`.

My problem is  that I work with `C#` since 4 weeks and I don't know how can I do that, I searched in the internet but I didn´t find any example. So I ask here for help.

Question:
How can I make the described requirement?, Is the requirement possible?

Picture for example:

[image]

Sorry for the bad picture, I have only Paint. That is my `MainWindow`  at the red arrow´s I want my tabs.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and `WindowsFormsApplication`

Comment: That sounds impossible (or way too difficult). Simply do it the other way round. Add tab pages to a tab control and add richtextboxes to that tab pages.

Comment: Richtextbox isn't a container for controls. Not possible.

Comment: That could be as simple as 3 `ToggleButton`'s (wpf, I think `CheckBox` with mode `Button` is in winforms?) and one `RichTextBox`. You sure you need tabs? Tabs means you will have different content, but it looks like you want to use same `RichTextBox`. You don't need tabs.

Comment: You can add richTextBox to tabControl, but the other way is not possible

Comment: No one can do that such requirement.

Comment: When i start the program i haven´t any tab. Now when i want see a single client i want see the communication in an extra window that window i want as an tab of the main window. When i can´t do that with a richtextbox, i can use sth other but what i need than?

Comment: I post my main window now as picture i hope someone can tell me what i must change or what i must do.

Comment: Do it the other way. Create a custom control that inherits from TabPage and have a richtextbox, then add it to a tabcontrol control. If you need a step by step guide ask and I will post it in a answer

Comment: It will be nice when you can write that as an answer than i know what i have to do. Thanks ahead.

Comment: @sniffi Give me some minutes and I post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it the other way arround, add richtextbox to tabpages.

It can be more simple if you make a custom control that inherits from tabpage. The problem with it is that you will be unable to design it via the visual editor. But since you need just one control in it you can add it via code.

The class for the custom tab is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class CustomTab:TabPage
    {
        public RichTextBox textbox;
        public CustomTab()
        {
            textbox = new RichTextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(textbox);
            textbox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it just inherits from tabpage and on the constructor it adds a RichTextBox that is docked in fill so it will cover all the page.

The textbox is public, so you can acces it simply with `tab.textbox`.

To add the tabs to the tabcontrol you just need to add the tabcontrol to the form and when you want to add the page simply:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new CustomTab());
```

Having a custom tab allows you to have all the data and methods that you want (Wich client it is for example)

If you have any quaestion feel free to ask